# Unable to lookup in Maven Test Harness

Tags: maven

I am trying to use Maven Test Harness to test the custom plugin. However, it is giving an error when looking up plugin by the goal name

> Running com.example.maven.plugins.test.MyMojoTest
> Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.215 sec <<< FAILURE!
> testSomething(com.example.maven.plugins.test.MyMojoTest)  Time elapsed: 1.135 sec  <<< ERROR!
> org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException: java.util.NoSuchElementException
> role: org.apache.maven.plugin.Mojo

```
package com.example.maven.plugins;

import org.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractMojo;
import org.apache.maven.plugins.annotations.Mojo;

/**
 * Says "Hi" to the user.
 *
 */
@Mojo( name = "sayHi")
public class MyMojo extends AbstractMojo
{
    public void execute() {
        getLog().info( "Hello, world." );
    }
}
```

```
package com.example.maven.plugins.test;

import com.example.maven.plugins.MyMojo;
import org.apache.maven.plugin.testing.AbstractMojoTestCase;
import org.apache.maven.plugin.testing.MojoRule;
import org.junit.Rule;

import java.io.File;

public class MyMojoTest
        extends AbstractMojoTestCase
{
    /** {@inheritDoc} */
    protected void setUp()
            throws Exception
    {
        // required
        super.setUp();


    }

    /** {@inheritDoc} */
    protected void tearDown()
            throws Exception
    {
        // required
        super.tearDown();


    }
    @Rule
    public MojoRule rule = new MojoRule() {
        @Override
        protected void before() {
        }

        @Override
        protected void after() {
        }
    };
    /**
     */
    public void testSomething() throws Exception {
        File pom = getTestFile( "src/test/resources/unit/project-to-test/pom.xml" );
        assertNotNull( pom );
        assertTrue( pom.exists() );

        MyMojo myMojo = (MyMojo)rule.lookupMojo("sayHi",pom);
        assertNotNull( myMojo );
       
        myMojo.execute();


    }
}
```

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.examplea.maven.plugin</groupId>
    <artifactId>project-to-test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>Test MyMojo</name>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>test-my-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>sayHi</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- Specify the MyMojo parameter -->
<!--                    <outputDirectory>target/test-harness/project-to-test</outputDirectory>-->
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Which version of harness etc. JDK, Maven Version etc. do you use? Best would be an example project on github or alike...

Comment: maven-plugin-testing-harness version is 3.3.0.  Intellji is showing Maven 3 bundled. I used Java 17 to run but the compiler version in Maven is 11.

Comment: Which version of Maven do you use? Which IntelliJ version do you use? Not running your tests on command line?

Comment: I am on IntelliJ IDEA 2021.3.3 (Ultimate Edition). Running from command line gives the same result